# How to download and setup SQLPlus for running SQL commands?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, instantclient

Today I attempted my first SQL class where I had to login by providing my login details and learned some introductory syntax. But I already got my first SQL assignment where I have to create a table and enter values. For that, I need to download SQL plus onto my computer. I opened the Oracle website and got confused. Didn't understand how to do it. Neither could I find a good step-by-step set of instructions that I can understand and follow. Please provide a step-by-step process with links through which I can download it properly. Also, I would like to say that my school provided SQL plus software, but it isn't running and is throwing an error `ocl.dll` error. I really need your help.

Comment: Look at [this](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130507065618AAhDxQb) link

Comment: Are you sure you need SQL*Plus and not Oracle SQL Developer?  The command-line SQL*Plus is useful for some things, but most development is much easier with an IDE like Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: I am not sure of that. But in my school, we started with a sql plus. Can you write the both process as an answer?  So that I can follow it and accept?

Comment: About "ocl.dll". SQL Plus software, provided by your's school contains just extracted contents of SQL Plus folder from `Program Files` folder, or it is an installer? If first - then thats means that some parts of app is missing, as they usually placed by installer in such folders as `Windows\System 32`, `Program Files\Common Files` and others. If second - then, probably, Windows versions differs. Same for other OS'es.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need SQL*Plus you can download the Oracle Instant client from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Install this and make sure you have the SQL*Plus exe on your path.

Alternatively you can also use Oracle SQLDeveloper from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or SQLcl which is a java based  command line for Oracle SQL based on the SQL engine we built for SQLDeveloper.  You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html#).

SQLcl is very easy and you can connect to any Oracle database using EZconnect syntax

```
sql.exe usernamepassword@yourdatabasemachinename:yoursqlportnumber/databasename
```

e.g.,

```
sql barry/omagh@devbox:1521/DEVDB1
```

Any questions on these, take a look at the community pages [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/community/index.html).

Hope this helps.

B

Answer (score 3):

I recently did this for Oracle 19c

1. Download SqlPlus instant client - `instantclient-sqlplus-windows.zip`
2. Download Instant Client - `instantclient-basiclite-windows.x64-19.9.0.0.0dbru.zip`
3. Extract files from step #2 into some folder, e.g. `c:\Program Files\OraInstClient`
4. Extract files from step #1 into the **same** folder
5. Add this folder to the `PATH` Environment Variable in your Windows system
6. Open CMD window and type `sqlplus`

To connect without `tnsnames.ora` use this syntax

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus /nolog 
SQL> connect sys@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostname)(PORT=1522))
 (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myServiceName)))' as sysdba
Enter Password:
Connected.
SQL>
```

Optionally, under same folder, create structure - `network\admin\tnsname.ora` and create TNS name in there

Answer (score 2):

I felt adding sql server and installing took a lot to discover and understand so I am adding some steps to get the same usage that one can find using sql+ tool. This installation is for oracle 11g express edition.
[This is the link from which you can download oracle database software](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html).

1. extract the zip file (don't change the name)
2. Start the "Setup"
3. when asked to choose password choose something you
   will not forget and write it down
   because this can't be changed easily later
4. When it will be installed completely, you will
   see a shortcut in desktop which in most of the cases doesn't work
5. Open your browser type this link

   http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

Caution: this port number can be 8081 or something else with respect to your free ports. If its occupied then when installing a window will appear having a PORT number section, one can see the number there.

6. You will see an Oracle window, choose "Application Express"
7. when you see a prompt of login put SYSTEM as user name
   and give the password you have chosen in 4th step
8. You will see another window "Create Application
   Express Workspace"
9. Choose "Create New" as "Database Username"
   Give a name to "Database Username" and that must be
   same with the next "Application Express Username"
10. Password same as 4th

11.You will see a window again where you have to
give your password

12. Now you will see 4 options
    choose "SQL Workshop"->"sql Commands"
13. You are all set and you can do everything here.
14. Otherwise CLIMAX: Go to search button of your pc
    type "Run SQL Command Line". You will see the
    Command Line Interface.
15. Type in the window after SQL>

    CONNECT USERNAME/PASSWORD

(these credentials are what you created in 9th and 10th
step)

Now you are ready to do whatever you want.